# How do I refer to my local computer for scp'ing when logged into remote?

Tags: unix, scp

This must be a really simple question, but I am trying to move a file from a remote server to my local computer, *while logged into the remote* (via ssh).

All of the guides say to just use

```
scp name@remote:/path/to/file local/path/to/file
```

But as far as I can understand, that would be what I would use from my local machine. From the remote machine, I assume that I want to use something like

```
scp /path/to/file my_local_computer:/local/path/to/file
```

but (if that's even correct) how do I know what to put in for my_local_computer?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I have been "attempting" for some time, and have searched quite a lot of manuals and forums.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can automatically figure out where you're logged in from by checking the environment variables SSH_CONNECTION and/or SSH_CLIENT. SSH_CONNECTION for example shows the client address, the outgoing port on the client, the server address and the incoming port on the server. See section ENVIRONMENT in `man ssh`

So, if you want to copy a file from the server to the client from which you're logged in from, the following (which infers the client ip by taking the first part of SSH_CONNECTION) should work:

```
scp /path/to/file $(echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -f 1 -d ' '):/local/path/to/file
```

Andreas

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track!  The man page for scp should tell you how to do what you want: http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp

If you are having trouble understanding the man page, then I will attempt to instruct you:

1. If you want to push a file from your local machine to a remote machine

   `scp /path/to/local/file testuser@remote-host:/path/to/where/you/want/to/put/file`
2. If you want to pull a file from a remote machine to your local machine

   `scp testuser@remote-host:/path/to/file/you/want/to/pull /path/on/local/machine/to/place/file`
3. If you are logged into a remote machine and want to push a file to your local machine (assuming you have the ability to scp to the local machine in the first place)

   `scp /path/on/remote/machine/to/file testuser@local-host:/path/on/local/machine/to/put/file`

Now, to determine what your local-host address is, you can check the IP address of your local machine or if your local machine has been provided a DNS entry, you could use it.

I.E., `scp ~/myfile testuser@192.168.1.10:/home/testuser/myfile OR scp ~/myfile testuser@my-host:/home/testuser/myfile`

For the DNS entry, provided you are on a correctly configured network, you would not need a fully qualified domain. Otherwise, you would need to do something like testuser@my-host.example.com:/home/testuser/myfile

Comment: I have a question: how to scp from a machine with local IP. I have sshed three time to access this machine. Is it possible to write something like this: `scp myusername1@85.185.211.20:myusername1@85.185.211.21:myusername2@192.168.20.18:/directory/to/the/file /mylocal/address` . note that there is 2 username for machines

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can build a solution around this:

```
who | grep $USER
```

When run on the remote computer, it should give a hint where you connected form.